# javascript Mouse over time delay like ebooks website

Tags: javascript

I need code for mouse over time delay, like ebooks.com (bestseller tab),
here is my javascript code,all are fine but i need time delay for onmouse over,

```
       var prevnum=0;
   var cate="cat1";
function mouseoverfn(id){

    document.getElementById("bestsellerin_book_"+id).style.display='block';
    prevnum!=id?document.getElementById("bestsellerin_book_"+prevnum).style.display='none':'';
    document.getElementById(cate).style.background='#ffffff';
    document.getElementById(cate).style.color='#000';
    document.getElementById(cate).style.posistion='absolute';
    mouseoutfn(id)
    prevnum=id;
}

function mouseoutfn(id){

    document.getElementById("bestsellerin_book_"+prevnum).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById("bestsellerin_book_"+id).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById("cat"+id).style.background='#94B83E';
    document.getElementById("cat"+id).style.color='#ffffff';


    cate="cat"+id;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="bestsellerin_txt_content" id="cat<?php echo $i; ?>" onmouseout="mouseoutfn(<?php echo $i; ?>)" onmouseover="mouseoverfn(<?php echo $i; ?>)">
    <span style="padding-left:4px;"><?php 
        echo substr(ucwords(strtolower($assigned_cat[$i]['Category']['name'])) , 0, 22);
        if( strlen($assigned_cat[$i]['Category']['name']) > 22){ 
            echo "..";
        }
    ?></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can stick a timeout in your mouseover func. If the user mouseout's before the timeout is up, the timeout gets canceled. (For this reason the timeout needs to be accessible to both your mouseover and mouseout handlers, as I demonstrate here).

```
(function() {

    var mo_timeout;

    function mouseover() {
        mo_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            //mouseover code here
        }, 1000);

    }

    function mouseoutfn(id){
        clearTimeout(mo_timeout);
        //mouseout code here
    }

})();
```

Also, that's a lot of styling you're adding manually; how about adding a class instead, which applies the styling?

Comment: He also needs to cancel the timeout in his mouseout function.

Comment: Pls explain as detail, i am beginner for javascript,setTimeout(function() {
            //mouseover code here
        }, 1000); i call which function.

Comment: You call `mouseoverfn` as you currently do - all I've done is wrapped the function's contents in a timeout. Inside that timeout, put the function contents.